# twitter api isn't returning truncated text

Tags: json, twitter

i'm making a JSon request for getting tweets of a specific user, here's my request url `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=booty&count=50`
i'm getting request's result but there's a problem, if returned tweet's text is long then it's getting truncated by default 
how can i get this truncated text? or can i disable this truncation? here's an example of returned truncated result

```
        {
    geo = "<null>";
    id = 848983209580822529;
    lang = en;
    place = "<null>";
    "possibly_sensitive" = 0;
    "retweet_count" = 8789;
    retweeted = 0;
    source = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>";
    text = "It was an honor to welcome President Al Sisi of Egypt to the @WhiteHouse as we renew the historic partnership betwe\U2026 "; // here can see the text is truncated 
    truncated = 1;
}
```

result text : `It was an honor to welcome President Al Sisi of Egypt to the @WhiteHouse as we renew the historic partnership betwe....`

here's the original tweet's text :
`It was an honor to welcome President Al Sisi of Egypt to the @WhiteHouse as we renew the historic partnership between the U.S. and Egypt.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after hours of research i found out all i needed was correct keyword for my google search, adding `tweet_mode=extended` in request Url did the job.

previous url : `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=booty&count=50`

correct url : `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=booty&count=50&tweet_mode=extended`

and for getting the text use `full_text` instead of `text` key.

more detail here --> https://twittercommunity.com/t/truncated-text-and-media-entities-not-returned/74358